# how to design person table for a movie database

Tags: database, erd

there is a problem of designing a movie database. A movie can only have one director and many actors and many writers, also the actors should be stored in a CAST table which shows the role of each actor in the movie and the STAR ACTOR should be identified.

how should i implement this? any help

here is the ERD
[image]

Comment: you can further normalize the `fact-movie`

Comment: i have created two association tables between actors/movie and writer/movie, but there is a confusion of how to implement the person table between the actor,director and writer, should i create separate table for each of them or a super and sub type?

Comment: "*A movie can only have one director*" - are you aware that that is a simplification which is not true in real life?

Comment: yes, i knew, this is not a real life project.

Comment: Are you designing the database or analyzing the subject matter?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a separate table for each of writer, director, and actor. It seems as though the data you'd like to store for actors (i.e. "Star Actor") wouldn't ever apply to a director or a writer.

OR

Make an actors table, and a separate "crew" table, which could include both directors and writers. A column in the crew table could be "profession" or something like that, which would be a foreign key to a "profession" table.

So I'd say that at minimum you'd want a separate table for the actors.